# Trying to get the average of 3 2-digit numbers NASM x86

Tags: nasm

I've seen other similar questions and I've tried the solutions mentioned but my code simply doesn't work. It gets three 2-digit numbers and adds it, divides by 3 to get the floored average, and prints it. Originally it works with the sum of numbers < 255, now I'm trying to make it work for cases > 255. With this code I'm getting Floating point exception (core dumped) in the terminal, and I'm at a loss why.

```
; i have successfully scanned, converted and joined the 3 numbers as n1o, n2o, n3o

; add to al, then ax
    mov ax, 0

    add al, [n1o]
    add al, [n2o]
    add ax, [n3o]   ; to prevent loss of sum > 255
    ; will this work?

; average
    mov bl, 3
    div bl          ; divide ax by 3

; split
    mov ah, 0       ; clear remainder of average
    mov bl, 10
    div bl

; assign to a1
    mov [a1t], al
    mov [a1o], ah

; convert a1

; print a1

; terminate
```

EDIT: my declarations

```
; n1
    n1t resb 1
    n1o resb 1

; n2
    n2t resb 1
    n2o resb 1

; n3
    n3t resb 1
    n3o resb 1

; a1
    a1t resb 1
    a1o resb 1
    ; reflects the average

; s1
    s1w resw 1
    ; sum of n1 n2 n3
```

Comment: Show the declarations of `a1t ato` and `n1o n2o and n3o`. At first guess you may be using byte holders (< 255) for word results (> 255).

Comment: Edited the original post :)

Comment: Try doing the 16 bit approach. `xor dx, dx` prior, then check that `bh` does not have a value and only `bl` does , then divide by `bx` and check `dx' for the remainder

Comment: @FrankC. Why would I check `dx` for remainder? I don't understand. Anyways, I did as what you said, after `div bx` the average should be in `ax` with only the `al` used, right? For some reason it outputs the wrong answer (input 99 99 99 yields B4, with 11 11 11 as 96) currently working on a solution now.

Comment: If you read the Intel `div` instruction for dividing 16 bit numbers, that is how it handles it http://eun.github.io/Intel-Pentium-Instruction-Set-Reference/data/div.html. BTW: You should be checking `ax` for the quotient and `dx` for the remainder, not just the lower byte.

Comment: Weird. I rewrote my code from scratch. After adding three variables where the joined numbers will be stored, and shifting the join code around (which resulted in a longer code) I can now 'div' by 'bl' only, and the 16-bit approach you suggested works too. Thanks!